# UNIX Join Command not working

Tags: unix, join, inner-join

I have 2 tab delimited files (sorted) that I am trying to inner join :

File 1:

```
01130164254     01/29/2008
01130165543     05/16/2011
01130168864     07/14/2009
01635163349     11/24/2009
```

File 2:

```
0.11    73379268872
0.64    67119603398
0.65    67261704102
16.11   01635163349
```

The 2nd column of the 2nd file and 1st column of the first file are the common columns on the basis of which I want to join the files. When I tried the command :

```
  join -t" " -1 1 -2 1 File 1 File 2
```

I get no output. But when I try this command :

```
join -t"  "  -a 2 -a 1 -e 'NULL' -o '0,1.1,1.2,2.1,2.2' File1 File2
```

I am getting a result out of this which unfortunately means that UNIX is not finding a common key for the files to join and it is surprising because there ARE common values between the files. This is how the sample of the result looks like

```
01635158332 09/09/2016 01635158332  09/09/2016 NULL NULL NULL
01635163349 11/24/2009 01635163349  11/24/2009 NULL NULL NULL
16.11   01635163339 NULL NULL 16.11 01635163339 NULL
16.11   01635163349 NULL NULL 16.11 01635163349 NULL
```

As you can see above, 01635163349 is a common key between File 1 that has dates and file 2 that has the cost. So ideally the result should be

```
01635163349  11/24/2009  16.11
```

Also, File 2 is a full dump file and File 1 is a daily delta file.

Is there any other way I can create an inner join between these 2 files? Please Help!!

Answer (score 1):

The input to `join` needs to be sorted *on the field you are joining on*.

```
sort -t $'\t' "File 2" |
join -t $'\t' -1 1 -2 1 "File 1" -
```